# Maximum number of enum elements in Java

Tags: java, enums, switch-statement

What is the maximum number of elements allowed in an enum in Java?

I wanted to find out the maximum number of cases in a switch statement. Since the largest primitive type allowed in switch is int, we have cases from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 and one default case. However enums are also allowed... so the question..

Comment: I have no idea, but would like to know what type of code are you thinking of that would require to know the max size of an enum lol

Comment: If a see s switch with 2 billion cases, I'll probably kill anyone that has touched that code.

Comment: Consider that the bytecode inside one case would take, say, 10 bytes of heap. Then the cases from cases from -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 would take 40 GB of RAM. And if each case statement takes 3 lines of source code, you have 12884901885 lines of code there. That's a hefty class :-)

Comment: @Rnet -- I have a suggestion. Why not start typing as many enums as you can and keep compiling and running and see when it break.  Good luck =)

Comment: Also worth noting is that Java 7 is going to allow switching on Strings, so your goal of finding the "maximum number of switch cases" is probably even more misguided than it seems.

Comment: For no practical purposes, just had a pondering :)

Comment: @BeemerGuy Tried generating the file through a loop in python, however javac runs out of heap space, my hardware limitation

Comment: @Rnet -- you actually tried it??? O.o

Comment: Yes, generated each element as print "A"+str(i)+"," , where i in an index in a loop...

Answer (score 34, accepted):

From the [class file format spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se5.0/html/ClassFile.doc.html#88659):

> The per-class or per-interface constant pool is limited to 65535 entries by the 16-bit constant_pool_count field of the ClassFile structure (§4.1). This acts as an internal limit on the total complexity of a single class or interface.

I believe that this implies that you cannot have more then 65535 named "things" in a single class, which would also limit the number of enum constants.

> If a see a switch with 2 billion cases, I'll probably kill anyone that has touched that code.

Fortunately, that cannot happen:

> The amount of code per non-native, non-abstract method is limited to 65536 bytes by the sizes of the indices in the exception_table of the Code attribute (§4.7.3), in the LineNumberTable attribute (§4.7.8), and in the LocalVariableTable attribute (§4.7.9).

Comment: LineNumberTable is not a blocker - one can write the complete switch/2 billion case block in a single line ;)

Comment: @Andreas_D: it still says "65536 bytes (of byte code) per method". Source formatting should not have any effect there.

Comment: (my comment was nothing but a joke)

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer seems to be incorrect.  While the logic seems plausible, it doesn't work that way in reality.  In Java 7 and 8, Enum constants in a single java file are limited to 2746.  Anything larger than 2746 will result in a "error: code too large"

Comment: @Derek: Good information.  Do you have a link to reference?

Comment: @Derek This is false. I just tested it myself, you can make a basic test program that generates an enum with 2800 entries and the program works just fine. I have no idea where he got this false notion from. The original answer is likely correct.

Comment: @Brayden I would like to know the environment where you are able to achieve the 2800.  The proof is posted as a response to the question, below.  Using a simple generation tool, create an enum with any number of entries.  The limit I get with MacOS, OEL Linux, and Windows is 2746.  This is very reproducible in every environment I have access to.

Comment: @Derek All I did was make a class that generates 2800 enum keys. I copied and pasted those into an Enum class. Then, I wrote a main() function that called name() on the 2800th enum key to verify that it wouldn't crash the program. Additionally, I had it do a for loop on all the keys and print name() and the index as well. I had no issues. I'm running Windows 7 and the Eclipse IDE for my Java-coding. I hope this helps. EDIT: Here's the code that prints out the 2800th key: https://pastebin.com/w8JSsVfq. When I run it, I successfully get ``This is ENUMKEY_2799``

Comment: @Brayden I tried to compile your code, but the compiler exits with "code too large".  If I delete entries out of your code down to 2745 entries or smaller, the code compiles and runs.  I get the same behavior on Windows 10, RH Linux 7.2, and MacOS.  On this test, I only used JDK 1.8_u191.

Comment: @Derek What IDE are you using? I'd imagine it might have something to do with that then. I recently upgraded to Windows 10 and re-tested my code just now and it still works. To be more specific on my own configuration, I used JDK1.8.0_171. My Eclipse version is Oxygen.3a Release (4.7.3a). I really don't know why you're having issues but I wish you luck in figuring out the solution. Be sure to post it here once you do so others who may have the same problem can find the solution.

Comment: @Anonymous So weird. They accepted and fixed a bug report about what you seem to see working...?
https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-8241798

Answer (score 28):

The maximum number of enum elements is 2746.  Reading the spec was very misleading and caused me to create a flawed design with the assumption I would never hit the 64K or even 32K high-water mark.  Unfortunately, the number is much lower than the spec seems to indicate.  As a test, I tried the following with both Java 7 and Java 8:  Ran the following code redirecting it to a file, then compiled the resulting .java file.

```
    System.out.println("public enum EnumSizeTest {");
    int max = 2746;
    for ( int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        System.out.println("VAR"+i+",");
    }
    System.out.println("VAR"+max+"}");
```

Result, 2746 works, and 2747 does not.

After 2746 entries, the compiler throws a code too large error, like

> EnumSizeTest.java:2: error: code too large

Decompiling this Enum class file, the restriction appears to be caused by the code generated for each enum value in the static constructor (mostly).

Comment: It seems there should be something about that limit in the language spec. It cannot be up to the compiler to decide how much it wants to allow. What error message did you get?

Comment: I edited the post to answer your question and further explain my response.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you use a 32 bit or 64 bit JDK/JRE?

Comment: I used the 64 bit JDK on a Linux and a Windows OS.  I ran the test again today on:java version "1.8.0_111"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_111-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.111-b14, mixed mode)

Comment: Apparently the overhead of the newer version is higher.  with 1.8.0_111, the max is now 2745 enums.

Comment: The limit of 2746 seems to be right. We hit the limit with generated enums.

Comment: Are you executing the code from Eclipse? Another response is talking about this limitation of 2747 entries in the IDE.

Comment: I ran this from the command-line with only the JDK java and javac.  I replicated the same on Windows 64-bit, macOS, and Linux.

Answer (score 11):

Enums definitely have limits, with the primary (hard) limit around 32K values. They are subject to Java class maximums, both of the 'constant pool' (64K entries) and -- in some compiler versions -- to a method size limit (64K bytecode) on the static initializer.

'Enum' initialization internally, uses two constants per value -- a FieldRef and a Utf8 string. This gives the "hard limit" at ~32K values.

Older compilers (Eclipse Indigo at least) also run into an issue as to the static initializer method-size. With 24 bytes of bytecode required to instantiate each value & add it to the values array. a limit around 2730 values may be encountered.

Newer compilers (JDK 7 at least) automatically split large static initializers off into methods named `" enum constant initialization$2"`, `" enum constant initialization$3"` etc so are not subject to the second limit.

You can disassemble bytecode via `javap -v -c YourEnum.class` to see how this works.

[It might be theoretically possible to write an "old-style" Enum class as handcoded Java, to break the 32K limit and approach close to 64K values. The approach would be to initialize the enum values by *reflection* to avoid needing string constants in the pool. I tested this approach and it works in Java 7, but the desirability of such an approach (safety issues) are questionable.]

*Note to editors:  Utf8 was an internal type in the Java classfile IIRC, it's not a typo to be corrected.*

Comment: Thomas, is there some bug/spec I can read up on the splitting of enum initializers into multiple methods? I have a (generated) enum that's compiling fine with the Eclipse Java compiler but fails on javac from JDK 8.

Comment: Hi @Gunnar, I think this is just a feature of the Eclipse ECJ compiler. Their compiler is better than Sun/ Oracle's.

Answer (score 7):

Well, on jdk1.6 I hit this limit.  Someone has 10,000 enum in an xsd and when we generate, we get a 60,000 line enum file and I get a nice java compiler error of

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.0.2:compile (default-compile) on project framework: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /Users/dhiller/Space/ifp-core/framework/target/generated-sources/com/framework/util/LanguageCodeSimpleType.java:[7627,4] code too large

so quite possibly the limit is much lower than the other answers here OR maybe the comments and such that are generated are taking up too much space.  Notice the line number is 7627 in the java compiler error though if the line limit is 7627, I wonder what the line length limit is ;) which may be similar.  ie. the limits may be not be based on number of enums but line length limits or number of lines in the file limit so you would have rename enums to A, B, etc. to be very small to fit more enums into the enum.

I can't believe someone wrote an xsd with a 10,000 enum..they must have generated this portion of the xsd.

Answer (score 7):

### Update for Java 15+

In JDK 15, the maximal number of constants in enums was raised to about 4103: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8241798

This was achieved by splitting the static initializer into two parts:

Before Java 15 (pseudocode):

```
enum E extends Enum<E> {
    ...

    static {
        C1 = new E(...);
        C2 = new E(...);
        ...
        CN = new E(...);
        $VALUES = new E[N];
        $VALUES[0] = C1;
        $VALUES[1] = C2;
        ...
        $VALUES[N-1] = CN;
    }
}
```

Since Java 15:

```
enum E extends Enum<E> {
    ...

    static {
        C1 = new E(...);
        C2 = new E(...);
        ...
        CN = new E(...);
        $VALUES = $values();
    }

    private static E[] $values() {
        E[] array = new E[N];
        array[0] = C1;
        array[1] = C2;
        ...
        array[N-1] = CN;
        return array ;
    }
}
```

This allowed the static initializer to contain more code (until it hits the 64 kilobytes limit) and therefore to initialize more enum constants.

Answer (score 2):

The maximum size of any method in Java is 65536 bytes. While you can theoretically have a large switch or more enum values, its the maximum size of a method you are likely to hit first.

Answer (score 0):

The `Enum` class uses an `int` to track each value's ordinal, so the max would be the same as int at best, if not much lower.

And as others have said, if you have to ask you're Doing It Wrong

Answer (score -3):

There is no maximum number *per se* for any practical purposes. If you need to define thousands of enums in one class you need to rewrite your program.

Comment: there is a maximum number for "practical purposes".  That is the number that works.  I think the point you are trying to make is that it is bad practice / bad style to define an enum with anywhere near that number of values.

Comment: LOL. What an argument. As if one would always have control over data structures. In many, many cases they are given externally and have nothing to do with your code. If there is a huge database that has developed over time, and you want to map a property into java to make it type-safe/compile-safe or whatever, that is a pretty reasonable thing to do. And you cannt count on the DB maintainer/admin/developer to take into account all languages' internal limitations.