# Invalid name: 'enum constant initialization$2' while installing app

Tags: java, android, dalvik, dex, dexopt

While installing android app from eclipse to any emulator I start getting error:

```
04-17 00:36:53.043: E/dalvikvm(20216): Invalid name: ' enum constant initialization$2'
04-17 00:36:53.043: E/dalvikvm(20216): Trouble with item 10075 @ offset 0x611ec
04-17 00:36:53.043: E/dalvikvm(20216): Cross-item verify of section type 0005 failed
04-17 00:36:53.043: E/dalvikvm(20216): ERROR: Byte swap + verify failed
04-17 00:36:53.043: E/dalvikvm(20216): Optimization failed
```

I have checked my enums but not sure what can be the problem. Don't find anything similar enough on net so need a bit of help here :)

Comment: Does the string "initialization" appear anywhere in your code?

Comment: No. I don't have that word anywhere in code.

Answer (score 0):

It looks that problem was with size of one of my big enums. i split that enum in two and problem went away.
It's pretty hard where is the problem becaus message don't say anything about concrete enum name where is the problem and what kind of problem is this. 
Just that Invalid name: 'enum constant initialization$2' crap.

Comment: See my answer as to where this comes from, and how to investigate (Java) bytecode in similar situations: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27515185/768795