# Complexity of enum.values()

Tags: java, enums, complexity-theory

I have a very simple Enum as follows:

`public enum Colour {
    RED, BLUE, GREEN;
}`

Here I've put three colours, but it may have a **undefined** size.

This Enum will be used in a class which can have an **undefined** number of instances (hundreds, thousands or even millions).

In this class I have a method that must return a random Colour.

I have two options for this.

```
private Colour[] colours;

public Datastructure() {

    colours = Colour.values();
}

public Colour getRandomColour() {
     return colours[rand.nextInt() % colours.length];
}
```

Or I can keep calling Colour.values() instead of creating the colours list.

```
public Colour getRandromColour() {
     return Colour.values()[rand.nexInt() % Colour.values().length]
```

In the first option, an extra array is created. Keep in mind that this class may have many instances, so it could be considered a waste of memory, and may have a impact on running time as well (instantiating the array). Especially when there are a lot of class instances.

In the second option, Colour.values() is called a few times (in this simple example it is only a few times but in my project it's bit more complex and has more calls) so this can be considered a waste of CPU usage.

I would prefer using the second option, but I'm curious about the complexity of the Colour.values() method, which I fear may be linear O(n). n being the number of Colours in the enum. This would be horrible when there are a lot of colours.

Or would it just be a weigh off and choose the best of two evils?

**tl;dr** What is the complexity of Enum.values()?

Comment: You're wasting your time trying to micro optimize something totally irrelevant.

Comment: @BoristheSpider explain?

Comment: Modulo is an expensive operation. You'd be much better of calling `rand.nextInt(values().length)`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider how is that obvious? Or even true? It can't just give you a reference to an existing array, because arrays are not read-only.

Comment: @Kayaman I don't really agree on the micro-optimizing. As I said, there may be a LOT of Colours and/or class instances. So this micro-optimizing might end up to be a big improvement.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Thank you for pointing out the modulo part. Could you explain why .values() is O(1)?

Comment: If micro-optimizing is your concern, you should use c++.

Comment: On closer inspection, @harold is right - I'm an idiot. [This SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1163121/2071828) reckons that `values()` is implemented as `array.clone()`.

Comment: @Auberon how many is your "lots of colors"? Because I suspect that if you really did have a large amount of colors, you'd use a database to store it and not an enum.

Comment: @Kayaman Undefined. Could be two, could be a million. I have no knowledge of databases as of yet. So I won't be considering a database as an option.

Comment: @Auberon Then consider [this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468388/maximum-number-of-enum-elements-in-java) which would give the maximum number of enum elements as 65535.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The array returned by `Colour.values()` always contains the same elements, but `values()` creates a *new* array every time it's called (so it's O(n) where n is the number of enum values). And you never modify that array. So calling the method every time you need it is a waste of time. And storing an array in every instance of your DataStructure class is a waste of time and memory. I would simply call the method once and cache that array in a constant:

```
private static final Colour[] COLOURS = colour.values();

public Colour getRandomColour() {
    return COLOURS[rand.nextInt(COLOURS.length)];
}
```

Just make sure this array is never exposed outside of the class.

Also note the usage of `Random.nextInt(limit)` which does exactly what you want, is probably faster, and expressed the intent more clearly than using a modulo.

Comment: Thank you. Kind of weird I didn't think of this. Could you modify your answer so it mentions the things pointed out by @BoristheSpider? (Modulo is expensive + .values() is ~equivalent~ to .clone(), which is O(n))

Comment: @Auberon answer modified.

Comment: Personally, I'd do all this inside the enum class itself (define `rand` and `COLORS` as private static members thereof, and `getRandomColour` as public static). Keeps `Colour` related functions encapsulated in `Colour`.

Comment: @RealSkeptic it's of course a valid option. It mainly depends on how you consider `getRandomColour()`: is it a method that is useful in general and that many classes will need to call, or is it something that is useful only in a specific use-case and that should not pollute the public API of the enum?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just put the cached array in a static field of Colour enum itself. then provide a method in the Colour enum to return a random entry.

It makes sense for the Colour enum to own this piece of data/method anyway.