# Load huge Enum from configuration or properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have a big enum with more than 4000 values. I can not code because the code is too long and also I don't feel that is the best way to do it.

I need enum class for example Animals. And all the animals should be read from a file. How can I do it in a nice way? I can use plain Java or Spring.

Thanks

Comment: With 4000 values it sound more like you need a POJO class that is persisted.

Answer (score 2):

As Joakim pointed out, what you are trying to achieve is probably a bad idea. What is your exact need? What do you intend to do with that enum?

Even if maintaining a 4000-case enum *was* a good idea, you're in the same order of magnitude as the maximum number of values in an enum (cf [Maximum number of enum elements in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468388/maximum-number-of-enum-elements-in-java)). I guess that you cannot be 100% certain that you will not exceed it one day.

You'd probably be better off with a dedicated class, pattern, database, ...

Comment: I need to have this enum to check incoming data if this data is in one of the categories we have in the file (The file is provided and it can change, and I really dont care what categories are inside)

Comment: @Guel135 This is not what enums are for. They're for easier _programmatic_ access to a set of predefined values. If you don't need to access specific enum constants programmaticaly (and it seems you don't), you should use a simple set of objects of a dedicated class, as Saucistophe suggested. You can use `java.util.LinkedHashSet`, or - if you can use Guava - `com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet`.