# Advantages of Java's enum over the old "Typesafe Enum" pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns, enums, language-design

In Java prior to JDK1.5, the "Typesafe Enum" pattern was the usual way to implement a type that can only take a finite number of values:

```
public class Suit {
    private final String name;

    public static final Suit CLUBS =new Suit("clubs");
    public static final Suit DIAMONDS =new Suit("diamonds");
    public static final Suit HEARTS =new Suit("hearts");
    public static final Suit SPADES =new Suit("spades");    

    private Suit(String name){
        this.name =name;
    }
    public String toString(){
        return name;
    }
}
```

(see e.g. Item 21 from Bloch's *Effective Java*).

Now in JDK1.5+, the "official" way is obviously to use `enum`:

```
public enum Suit {
  CLUBS("clubs"), DIAMONDS("diamonds"), HEARTS("hearts"), SPADES("spades");

  private final String name;

  private Suit(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Obviously, the syntax is a bit nicer and more concise (no need to explicitly define fields for the values, suitable `toString()` provided), but so far `enum` looks very much like the Typesafe Enum pattern.

Other differences I am aware of:

- enums automatically provide a `values()` method
- enums can be used in `switch()` (and the compiler even checks that you don't forget a value)

But this all looks like little more than syntactic sugar, with even a few limitations thrown in (e.g. `enum` always inherits from `java.lang.Enum`, and cannot be subclassed).

Are there other, more fundamental benefits that `enum` provides that could not be realized with the Typesafe Enum pattern?

Comment: real advantage: serialization is faster. The rest can be emulated.

Comment: @sleske what do u mean by Compiler checks in switch . I haven't heard of that feature . It's better not to use switch rather implement a concrete method for each enumeration value for an abstract method .

Comment: @user1198898: The compiler will show an error if you repeat a `case` in your switch, and it can warn if not all enum values are covered by the cases. And yes, often it's better to use polymorphism instead of a switch, but this depends on circumstances.

Comment: @sleske thanks for clearing that out.

Answer (score 16):

- "cannot be subclassed" isn't a restriction. It's one of the big advantages: It ensures there there is always only ever exactly the set of values defined in the `enum` and no more!
- `enum` correctly handles serialization. You *can* do that with type-safe enums as well, but it's often forgotten (or simply not known). This ensures that `e1.equals(e2)` **always** implies `e1 == e2` for any two `enum` values `e1` and `e2` (and vice versa, which is probably more important).
- There are specific lightweight data structures that handle enums: `EnumSet` and `EnumMap` (stolen from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2077634/enum-in-java-advantages/2079514#2079514))

Comment: I don't think you can subclass a class with only a private constructor anyhow...except nested within the class itself.

Comment: @Mark: true, but you could modify the class to have a `protected` constructor instead.

Comment: Yeah I would think that the constructor should be private and the class made final.

Comment: +1 serialization.  It's also as iron-clad as you can get against adding values to the enum at run-time.  I do sorta wish that each value of an enum was a final subclass, but I guess you can't have both (can you?)

Answer (score 12):

Of course there are lots of advantages other people will mention here as answers. Most importantly, you can write `enums` very fast and they do a lot of things like implement `Serializable`, `Comparable`, `equals()`, `toString()`, `hashCode()`, etc, which you didn't include in your enum.

But I can show you a **serious drawback** of `enum` (IMO). Not only can't you subclass them at will, but you can't equip them with a generic parameter. When you could write this:

```
// A model class for SQL data types and their mapping to Java types
public class DataType<T> {
    private final String name;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public static final DataType<Integer> INT      = new DataType<Integer>("int", Integer.class);
    public static final DataType<Integer> INT4     = new DataType<Integer>("int4", Integer.class);
    public static final DataType<Integer> INTEGER  = new DataType<Integer>("integer", Integer.class);
    public static final DataType<Long>    BIGINT   = new DataType<Long>("bigint", Long.class);    

    private DataType(String name, Class<T> type){
        this.name = name;
        this.type = type;
    }

    // Returns T. I find this often very useful!
    public T parse(String string) throws Exception {
        // [...]
    }
}

class Utility {

    // Enums equipped with generic types...
    public static <T> T doStuff(DataType<T> type) {
        return ...
    }
}
```

This is not possible with an enum:

```
// This can't be done
public enum DataType<T> {

    // Neither can this...
    INT<Integer>("int", Integer.class), 
    INT4<Integer>("int4", Integer.class), 

    // [...]
}
```

Comment: I see what you mean, but I don't think the example is a good one. Why would I want `Club` as a separate type from `Diamond`. In my opinion they are quite explicitly different values of the same type, not separate types.

Comment: You're right. The example really just is an example. I'll try to display a real-world problem..

Comment: Another nitpick: to make your sample actually typesafe, I'd keep `parse()` abstract in `DataType` and implement it in anonymous inner classes (one per value).

Comment: Thanks for the edit, Joachim. I just noticed at the very same time, that I wrote garbage :-) About `abstract`: That's not necessarily an improvement. All 3 `DataType<Integer>` implementations would probably share the same `parse(String)` code... So no gain there. But then again it's just an example...

Comment: You can subclass an enum, it just has to happen as an anonymous type. Anything else would break assumptions made by the specification.

Comment: @josefx, can you provide an example? How can you subclass an enum? `Enum` can't be subclassed, the compiler prevents that. And a concrete `enum` type cannot be subclassed either, because all constructors in an `enum` must be private...

Comment: @Lukas Eder enum AnEnum{HELLO(){public void print(){System.out.println("Hello");}}, WORLD(){public void print(){System.out.println("World");}}; public abstract void print();} ____________ Both the HELLO and WORLD values are implemented as  subclasses of AnEnum.

Comment: @josefx, interesting. I hadn't thought of that.

Comment: +1 Shame enum cant be used in this manner. Exactly what I needed... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> Now in JDK1.5+, the "official" way is
>   obviously to use `enum`:
>
> ```
> public enum Suit {
>   CLUBS("clubs"), DIAMONDS("diamonds"), HEARTS("hearts"), SPADES("spades");
>
>   private final String name;
>
>   private Suit(String name) {
>     this.name = name;
>   }
> }
> ```

Actually, it's more like

```
 public enum Suit {
     CLUBS, DIAMONDS, HEARTS, SPADES;
 }
```

because enums already provide a `name()` method. Additionally, they provide an `ordinal()` method (which enables efficient data structures like `EnumSet` and `EnumMap`), implement `Serializable`, override `toString`, provide `values()` and `valueOf(String name)`. They can be used in a type safe switch statement, and are singletons.

Answer (score 3):

Your type-safe enum implementation is a bit oversimplified. When you deal with serialization it will become much more complicated.

Java `enum`s solve the problem with serialization/deserialization. `enum`'s are guarantied to be unique and you can compare them with `==` operator.

Read correspondent chapters in Effective Java 2nd Edition (about using enums instead of singletons, about using `EnumSet`s etc).

Comment: *using enums instead of singletons*? each enum item *is* a singleton!!

Comment: @Sean Patrick Floyd: Yes, it is, but it is more than that (and that's the point).

Answer (score 2):

[`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and [`EnumMap`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) are custom data structures that are built around the specific features of enums. They have handy extra features and they are extremely fast. There is no equivalent (at least not with equivalent elegance of use, see comments) to them without enums.

Comment: A `BitSet` is a very efficient replacement for `EnumSet` **iff** you replace your `enum` with `int` values instead of a typesafe enum pattern implementation.

Comment: @Joachim granted. but the API is much uglier and `EnumSet` has great factory methods: `copyOf()`, `complementOf()` etc.

Comment: i agree that `EnumSet` is much nicer. I just don't agree that "there is no equivalent".

Comment: You could just add an `ordinal()` method to your "typesafe enum class", and implement most of the rest based on it. But sure, `enum` gives a nicer way to write it, and all the infrastructure is already there.

Answer (score 2):

In addition:

JDK5 enums can be easily used in switch-case statements with good IDE support

```
Suit suit = ...; 
switch (suit) { 
    case SPADES: System.out.println("Motorhead!"); break;
    default: System.out.println("Boring ..");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Syntactic sugar alone is worth its salt :-P After all, that's what for ( : ) is, too.

But seriously, the fact to have automatically name() and ordinal() out of the box, to enumerate them, to use them in switch (), to attach additional values to them are good arguments for them: it avoids lot of boilerplate code.

The traditional lazy alternative, using ints, isn't typesafe and is much more limited.
A drawback of enums over this alternative is that they are no longer lightweight.

Comment: Actually, I believe enums are reasonably lightweight. In particular, if you actually use them in a quantity where it matters, you can use EnumSet and EnumMap, which are lightweight.