# Ranking in Java. How to set it?

Tags: java

I have a Class called ranking.
It has certain ranks: general, soldier, corporal, mayor.

Now I need to set it default by ranking:

1. soldier
2. corporal
3. mayor
4. general.

This is a member:

```
private static char Ranks[]; // size 4
```

Where can I set them by default like:

```
Ranks[0] = soldier;
Ranks[1] = corporal...
```

I don't really know where to put default values, so program will know that soldier by default is Ranks[0]. Into constructors? Into members?

Comment: why not using an enum?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092015/advantages-of-javas-enum-over-the-old-typesafe-enum-pattern

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd suggest to use an Enum instead.

You could have a constant in the class using the Enum to point out the default and have a constructor/setter to go with another instead.

```
public enum Rank {
    SOLDIER, CORPORAL, MAYOR, GENERAL
}
```

...

```
public class MilitaryPerson {

    private static final Rank DEFAULT_RANK = Rank.SOLDIER;

    private Rank rank;

    public MilitaryPerson() {
        this.rank = DEFAULT_RANK;
    }

    public MilitaryPerson(Rank rank) {
        this.rank = rank;
    }

    // ...

}
```

An alternate (and better) solution would be to have the default one set up in a config file (e.g. *.properties)

Comment: @SamSB The proper way of implementing enums can be studied at [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) site. I'd recommend throwing the hardcoded default away and using a config file though. [Property files](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/) are pretty good for such simple purposes.