# What would prevent adding properties to Enums in the C# language?

Tags: c#, enums

A pet peeve of mine in C# is the inability to add (read-only) properties to Enum types in C#. For example if we took a DayOfWeek Enum. We might want to have the ability to know if a given value falls on a weekday.

```
//Built in Enum but using for example. 
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0,
    Monday = 1,
    Tuesday = 2,
    Wednesday = 3,
    Thursday = 4,
    Friday = 5,
    Saturday = 6

    public bool IsWeekend
    {
        get
        {
            switch (this)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsWeekday(this DayOfWeek d)
    {
        //Not as nice as properties for reasons listed below.
    }
}
```

Now its of course possible to create extension methods taking an Enum as the first 'this' argument. But this has a few stylistic drawbacks that I can think of.

First, to access the extension method the user must include the correct using block at the top of the file.

Second, c# guidelines indicate that for a piece of information such as IsWeekday in the example, a read only property is more appropriate than a method.

Third, from my perspective the property syntax is more readable.

Forth, a property would allow the logic for IsWeekday to be encapsulated in the DayOfWeek Enum itself vs needing to create a separate class.

I could also see the ability to add methods, operator overloads, and implicit/explicit cast as quite useful.

I understand that this is not a current feature in C# and as far as I know it is not planned, and I doubt that too many others are clamoring for it. But, I was wondering if there were some concrete reasons that are not obvious to me that adding properties (or even methods, etc) to Enums would not make sense?

Comment: RE: first point; You _could_ just place the extension method in `namespace System { }`... RE: second point: A case could be made for `IEnumerable.Count()` where it may be better positioned as a proeprty, but I've had no heartburn with it being a method.

Comment: You can always add attributes to Enum values, and then use those as pseudo-properties

Comment: The answer is: nothing. Your logic is correct. The rest is speculation which is not a good fit for Stack Overflow. Use the User Voice site to bring your wish to attention.

Comment: @ Brad, interesting idea. Would that be considered ok when creating a class Library though?

Comment: @eoldre: I don't see why not. Katana (Owin) is using it for their `IAppBuilder` extensions to make integration seamless.

Comment: You're basically talking about [Java enumeration classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) but in C#, right?

Comment: @Christie: Enumerable.Count is a method and it can be an expensive one if the sequence is not a collection but a query.

Comment: My guess to answer the title question *What would prevent adding properties to Enums in the C# language?* would be the same as [Should C# warn on null dereference?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2012/07/17/should-c-warn-on-null-dereference.aspx) *Features cost money, time and effort, and take away money, time and effort from features that would benefit the user better, so features have to be justified based on a cost-vs-benefits analysis* This one isn't that useful as there are plenty of ways to accomplish what you want without it.

Answer (score 2):

If you truly need this functionality, there is the [typesafe enum pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092015/advantages-of-javas-enum-over-the-old-typesafe-enum-pattern).  For your specific example though, you can encode the functionality with flag enums.  You would define your enum as such:

```
[Flags]
public enum DayOfWeek
{
    Sunday = 0x1,
    Monday = 0x2,
    Tuesday = 0x4, 
    Wednesday = 0x8,
    Thursday = 0x10,
    Friday = 0x20,
    Saturday = 0x40,
    Weekend = Saturday | Sunday,
    Weekday = ~Weekend
}
```

And to check if a day is a Weekday, you can check as such:

```
public static bool IsWeekday(DayOfWeek day)
{
    return (day | DayOfWeek.Weekday) != 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What speaks against an `isWeekEnd` property in a class that uses that enum?

```
public class DayInfo
{
    public DayOfWeek CurrentDay{ get; set; }

    public bool IsWeekend
    {
        get
        {
            switch (CurrentDay)
            {
                case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
                case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
                    return true;
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You wouldn't ask why you can't extend `int` with a property without using an extension, would you?

Answer (score 1):

Enum is enumeration. Simple as that. It is a specific type. You can create wrapper class for your enumeration.

This is designed for simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a **distinct** type
>   that consists of a set of named **constants** called the enumerator list.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx

By definition, a mutable property within an enumeration would not work. When using an enumeration, you expect the value to be **constant**.

Comment: What mutable property?  There is no setter.  No backing field.