# GroovyWS collision in the ObjectFactory class

Tags: groovy, wsdl, groovyws

I'm using the sample app at http://groovy.codehaus.org/GroovyWS and just 
plugging in my WSDL / parameters.
After catching the exception and printing it out I see that the root problem 
is: Two declarations cause a collision in the ObjectFactory class.

I've googled around a bit and I see some solutions for JAXB implementations 
(i.e. schemabindings, factoryMethod).
Has anyone seen this before. Is there a clean way to resolve in GroovyWS?

Comment: So I tried a few wsdl->java tools and only Axis2 could successfully generate code. However, the code Axis2 generated refused to compile because there were too many SOAP faults being statically init'ed (apparently there is a limit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java).

Comment: I tried a python SOAP lib (suds) and it also (unsurprisingly) choked. So far the only thing I can get to hit this service is PHP5 w/ SoapClient. I would REALY prefer groovy or java but I also REALLY don't want to code this thing by hand.

Comment: I guess this is not a common error. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: my guess is that the problem is rooted in your wsdl. can you post it?

Comment: I can't actually post the wsdl - but I can tell you it is a valid wsdl and was generated from .NET. I don't have the capability to fix the wsdl as I don't own it.