# Android: Error: Code too large -- how to fix?

Tags: android, arrays, object, compilation

I have an `array` of `objects` in a class and it causes my program to not `compile`. I don't know the best way to split the objects up/if this is the best way to do it. From what I've seen, that is the only option or importing from a text file. I don't understand how my objects have take up 64 K bytes of memory? Is there a way I can see exactly how much memory my class is taking? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider storing data in string resource file (strings.xml) or SQLite then do eager/lazy loading as an object at run time.

About memory consumption, you can analyze it with DDMS.

[Debugging Memory](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-memory.html)

[“Code too large” compilation error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java)

Comment: is there another way of doing this without using a database?

Comment: possibly a properties file?

Comment: I meant it could be the arrays in the string resource file

Comment: will an object still be accessible if moved to the string resource file?