# Error When building App Method code too large

Tags: android, android-studio, build

I imported my project from existent code. I didn't do any modification but when I build the application there is the error:

> :XXXXPlayer:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug FAILED
>        FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> *What went wrong:
>    Execution failed for task ':xxxxPlayer:transformClassesWithInstantRunForDebug'.
>
> Method code too large!

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You should break your function into different functions. It is really bad design to create one large method.

Error is thrown because there is a 64K byte-code size limit on a method in Java.

There could be helpful http://chrononsystems.com/blog/method-size-limit-in-java

Also checkout solution proposed in this answer ["Code too large" compilation error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java)

Comment: Thank you for your response but the problem is that the build work in other machine so maybe the probleme is with the mac

Comment: Another important info, if you don't have time to check your code, you can turn 'debuggable' flag off. It works to me.

Answer (score 0):

Error is producing because you have added many dependencies.

First a java class name what you want for example `ApplicationDelegate` and extends with `MultiDexApplication`. 
Open android manifest file add this class name         `'android:name=".ApplicationDelegate"'` in Application Tag.!