# Error: Code too large in AppDatabase_Impl.java when I have more tables in database

Tags: android, android-room

I am using Room library in one of my app, and when compiling my app it gives me below error:

```
\db\AppDatabase_Impl.java:393: error: code too large 
protected void validateMigration(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db) { 
^ 
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API. 
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details. 
1 error 
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED 
:app:buildInfoGeneratorDebug 

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. 

* What went wrong: 
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. 
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
(see full text)
```

Comment: What's unclear about "code too large"?

Comment: @Henry I know about "code too large" but is there any way to get ride of it, as this class is generated Room libraray

Comment: The only way is to make it shorter.

Comment: Oh!!, Actually that class is auto generated by the library. Is there any way to increase this limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Code too large" compilation error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java)

Answer (score -2):

```
protected void validateMigration(SupportSQLiteDatabase _db)

Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

This is your error, go through that method and remove any calls to deprecated api then it should run