# Code too large for a method in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

As a reference from the https://stackoverflow.com/a/2407930/8970520 It was told to use properties file to extend the allocated size .But i couldn't understand how to do that.Could you please elaborate and explain how it works?Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not make the method smaller?

Comment: I can't make the method smaller because it contain data

Comment: data is not supposed to be inside the source code. Load it from an external resource, you already mentioned properties.

Comment: Where can i write the data? I don't know how to mention properties.Can you explain how?

Comment: Split the data in multiple parts and combine them at runtime.

Comment: What kind of data do you have inside a method that makes the method exceed 64KB of bytecode? **Edit** the question and show example.

Comment: Check this link.It has the method which i wrote.I am working on captcha.So i am loading data into an hashmap. https://onlinegdb.com/Hk9W08Egw

Comment: Wow, [that](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk9W08Egw) is just horrendous!!! Why would you store a **bit** as 1-character String objects? What a waste of memory. Each string object takes up *more than* 30 bytes of memory, to store one **bit**!!!

Comment: @Andreas I changed them to boolean which stores 1 bit https://onlinegdb.com/Hk9W08Egw even then it shows code too large

Comment: That's the same link.

Comment: http://tpcg.io/BRCfYHJU
@Andreas here is the link

Answer (score 1):

In this case, using the properties file to extend the size is the wrong approach. Some people have already pointed this out, but you really, *really* don't want to include data in the source code. If the data changes, you would have to recompile your application and do a re-deploy of your app.

If the data does not change frequently, you could consider an XML file or SQLite database. If the data changes, though, you'll definitely need a mechanism to update it (even if the data changes rarely). Perhaps consider a web service.

If the data changes frequently, you'll definitely want to consider a web service to download the data.

Comment: Data never changes but I need the data more often.

Comment: this is a good answer and i'm not disagreeing with this, but in the original link OP posted it also shows there that someone was doing relatively the same thing, so i don't know if this question is really any different to the one there, this might just be a duplicate entirely

Comment: @sandeysh In that case, I'd recommend a SQLite database or XML file.

Answer (score 1):

[Your code](https://onlinegdb.com/Hk9W08Egw) is like this:

```java
public String[] checks(String qww){
    Map<String, String[]> bitmaps  = new HashMap<>();
    String[] cs;
    cs=new String[]{"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", ... 775 more bits ... };
    bitmaps.put("a",cs);
    cs=new String[]{"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", ... 775 more bits ... };
    bitmaps.put("A",cs);
    ... 49 more entries ...
    return bitmaps.get(qww);
}
```

That is just wrong on so many levels:

1. Storing bits as 1-character strings is a waste of memory, since it uses **more than 30 bytes** per string, just to store a ***bit***.

   At the very least, you could have stored the bit-characters in a `char` array, created from a single string, e.g.

   ```java
   Map<String, char[]> bitmaps  = new HashMap<>();
   bitmaps.put("a", "11111 ... 775 more bits ...".toCharArray());
   bitmaps.put("A", "11111 ... 775 more bits ...".toCharArray());
   ... 49 more entries ...
   return bitmaps.get(qww);
   ```
2. The code builds up the entire `bitmaps` map on every call, then gets one of the map values and **discards the map**. Waste of processing time.

   Either build the `bitmaps` map once only, or use a `switch` statement instead:

   ```java
   public char[] checks(String qww) {
       switch (qww) {
           case "a": return "11111 ... 775 more bits ...".toCharArray();
           case "A": return "11111 ... 775 more bits ...".toCharArray();
           ... 49 more entries ...
           default: return null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. That amount of data should be stored outside the code, e.g. in a property file.

   When loaded into memory, the bits should be stored in a [`BitSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/BitSet.html)

So, first create a property file, e.g. `checks.bitmaps`. The name can be anything, it is just a text file. Content:

```
a = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111000000000111111110000000000000001111000000000000000001110000000000000000001100000000000000000001000111111110000000010111111111110000000011111111111110000000111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000111110000000000000111111110000000000001111111100000000000011111110000000000000111111000000000000000111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100000001000000000111000000011000000111110000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
A = 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111110000000011111111100000000000001111110000000000000000111100000000000000001111000001111100000001110011111111100000011101111111111100000111111111111111000001111111111111110000001111100000000000000011100000000000000000100000000000000000001000000000000000000000000000111111000000000000111111110000000000001111111100000000000011111110000000000000111111100000000000000111100000000010000000000000000000100000000000000000001100000000000100000011110000000111000000111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111
... 49 more entries ...
```

Another advantage of this is that the data is so much easier to view and edit.

Change the code as follows:

```java
class Main {
    private static final Map<String, BitSet> bitmaps = new HashMap<>();
    static {
        try (InputStream inStream = Main.class.getResourceAsStream("checks.bitmaps")) {
            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.load(inStream);
            for (String key : props.stringPropertyNames()) {
                char[] bits = props.getProperty(key).toCharArray();
                BitSet bitmap = new BitSet(bits.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < bits.length; i++)
                    bitmap.set(i, bits[i] == '1');
                bitmaps.put(key, bitmap);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Bitmap file failed to load: " + e, e);
        }
    }
    public BitSet checks(String qww) {
        return bitmaps.get(qww);
    }
}
```

The caller can now check for 1-bits as follows:

```java
BitSet bitmap = main.checks(qww);
if (bitmap.get(index)) {
    // Bit is '1'
} else {
    // Bit is '0'
}
```

Comment: Which is the best way out of three ways in my case? @Andreas

Comment: @sandeysh **All 3!** --- 1) the bits are stored as a single string of 0's and 1's, 2) the `bitmaps` map is only built once, 3) the data for the `bitmaps` map is stored outside the class. --- So, **the second half of the answer**, that's why I spent time writing all that.