# Method code too large! after android compileSdkVersion 27 change to compileSdkVersion 30

Tags: android, android-studio-3.2

I get an error in android studio after android compileSdkVersion 27 was updated to  compileSdkVersion 30 in androidx.
I implemented multidex and also java heap to 64, but there is no response.

error code:
 `Method code too large!`

`Method too large: com/yrkfgo/assxqx4/MraidView.`

Comment: Have you disabled instant run in settings? if not then disable it and try

Comment: Instant run is not found in my latest android studio 3.2.0

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Code too large" compilation error in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407912/code-too-large-compilation-error-in-java)